# When clicking on the search area the program goes one step backwards (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm working on an exercise on codepen and after clicking on the magnifier, writing the search and pressing enter. The search area moves up, until here are all works fine.

The problem comes when the search area has moved up, if I click on it (search area), it moves down again, it's like if the program resets to a step backward. I suppose that the form is causing that although I disabled it and I returned false.

Any ideas about what is causing this issue? How would you solve the problem?

Here you have the link to the code itself:
http://codepen.io/rafahuelin/pen/ygNKzQ

Warning: The code is not working fine on the snippet attached to this post, but I'm interested in it to work on codepen.

Thanks for helping out :)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Appears the magnifier icon
    $("#search").html("<div id='magnifier' class='search-init animated fadeIn'> <div id='magnifier-stick' class='stick-appears'></div> </div>");

    // When clicking on the icon appears the input form
    if ($("#magnifier")) {
        $("#search").on("click", function () {
            $("#magnifier-stick").addClass("animated fadeOut stick-disappears").removeClass("stick-appears");
            $(".search-init").addClass("search-input").removeClass("search-init");
            setTimeout(function () {  //waits for 1s
                $("#search").html("<div class='search-input'><form><input id='input-form' class='animated fadeIn' type='text' name='searchContent' placeholder='Type Your Search Here...'></form></div>");
                $("#input-form").focus();
            }, 1000);
        });
    }
    //After pressing Enter, 
    $("#search").on("submit", function (e) {
        var searchText = $("#input-form").val(); //<---JQuery  var searchText = document.getElementById("input-form").value; <---In javascript
        moveSearchUp(searchText);
        return false;
    });

    //send request to API


    //search-input moves up 
    function moveSearchUp(searchText) {
        $(".search-input").addClass("search-top").removeClass("search-input");

        setTimeout(function () {  //waits for 1s

            //$("#search").html("<div class='search-top'><form><input id='input-form' class='animated fadeIn' type='text' name='searchContent' value='" + searchText + "'></form></div>");
            $("#input-form").css({ 'width': searchText.length * 7 + 'px' });
        }, 500);
        //$("#input-form").attr("disabled", "disabled"); //Disable textbox to prevent
        $("#input-form").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#input-form").attr("disabled", "disabled"); //Disable textbox to prevent multiple submit
        $("#input-form").on("click", function (e) {
            return false;
        });

        // return false;
    } // end function moveSearchUp


}); // $(document).ready
```

```css
.test {
    background-color: yellow;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.search-init {
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    border: 4px solid green;
    border-radius: 35px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    -ms-animation-duration: 3s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
}

#magnifier-stick.stick-appears {
    height: 20px;
    width: 0;
    border: 2px solid green;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    top: 54px;
    left: 54px;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

#magnifier-stick.stick-disappears {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border: 2px solid green;
    transform: rotate(-95deg);
    top: 54px;
    left: 54px;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 200ms ease;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.2s;
    -ms-animation-duration: 0.2s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.2s;
}

#input-form, #input-form:focus {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 120px;
    border-radius: 35px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    transition: all 500ms 500ms ease;
}

.search-input {
    line-height: 56px;
    height: 70px;
    width: 570px;
    border: 4px solid green;
    border-radius: 35px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 500ms 500ms ease;
}

.search-top {
    line-height: 40px;
    height: 54px;
    border: 4px solid green;
    border-radius: 27px;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 500ms 500ms ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="search">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

 /* 
    YOU NEED tO RESET THIS FLAG 
    EVERYTIME YOU CLOSE YOUR 
    SEARCH BOX
 */ 
 var flag = 0;  
  
// Appears the magnifier icon
 $("#search").html("<div id='magnifier' class='search-init animated fadeIn'> <div id='magnifier-stick' class='stick-appears'></div> </div>");

// When clicking on the icon appears the input form
if($("#magnifier")) {
 $("#search").on("click", function() {
            if(!flag)
              {
   $("#magnifier-stick").addClass("animated fadeOut stick-disappears").removeClass("stick-appears");
   $(".search-init").addClass("search-input").removeClass("search-init");
   setTimeout(function() {  //waits for 1s
    $("#search").html("<div class='search-input'><form><input id='input-form' class='animated fadeIn' type='text' name='searchContent' placeholder='Type Your Search Here...'></form></div>");
    $("#input-form").focus();
   }, 1000);
            flag = 1;
         }
 });
}
//After pressing Enter, 
$("#search").on("submit", function(e) {
 var searchText = $("#input-form").val(); //<---JQuery  var searchText = document.getElementById("input-form").value; <---In javascript
 moveSearchUp(searchText);
 return false;
});
 
//send request to API

 
//search-input moves up 
function moveSearchUp(searchText) {
 $(".search-input").addClass("search-top").removeClass("search-input");
 
 setTimeout(function() {  //waits for 1s
    
    //$("#search").html("<div class='search-top'><form><input id='input-form' class='animated fadeIn' type='text' name='searchContent' value='" + searchText + "'></form></div>");
    $("#input-form").css({'width': searchText.length * 7 + 'px'});
   }, 500);
 //$("#input-form").attr("disabled", "disabled"); //Disable textbox to prevent
 $("#input-form").prop('disabled', true);
 $("#input-form").attr("disabled", "disabled"); //Disable textbox to prevent multiple submit
 $("#input-form").on("click", function(e) {
  return false;
 });
 
// return false;
} // end function moveSearchUp
 
 
}); // $(document).ready
```

```css
.test {
 background-color: yellow;
}

html {
 height: 100%;
}

body {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.search-init {
 height: 70px;
 width: 70px;
 border: 4px solid green;
 border-radius: 35px;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 position: absolute;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
 -ms-animation-duration: 3s;
 -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
}

#magnifier-stick.stick-appears {
 height: 20px;
 width: 0;
 border: 2px solid green;
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
 top: 54px;
 left: 54px;
 position: absolute;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

#magnifier-stick.stick-disappears {
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 border: 2px solid green;
 transform: rotate(-95deg);
 top: 54px;
 left: 54px;
 position: absolute;
 transition: all 200ms ease;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 0.2s;
 -ms-animation-duration: 0.2s;
 -moz-animation-duration: 0.2s;
}

#input-form, #input-form:focus {
 width: 100%;
 min-width: 120px;
 border-radius: 35px;
 outline: none;
 border: none;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 20px;
 transition: all 500ms 500ms ease;
}

.search-input{
 line-height: 56px;
 height: 70px;
 width: 570px;
 border: 4px solid green;
 border-radius: 35px;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 position: absolute;
 transition: all 500ms 500ms ease;
}

.search-top {
 line-height: 40px;
 height: 54px;
 border: 4px solid green;
 border-radius: 27px;
 top: 50px;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 position: absolute;
 transition: all 500ms 500ms ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="search">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks to your advice and vishal patel's I came up with an easier solution that is targeting the #magnifier instead of #search then I avoid to use any if statement.

Answer (score 1):

I have done some minor changes to your code and its working as you are expecting. The problem was click function on your div search was triggering multiple times and it was resetting it.So I added flag to let it run only first time.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var clicked = false;  // Set flag to allow click only one time
// Appears the magnifier icon
$("#search").html("<div id='magnifier' class='search-init animated    fadeIn'> <div id='magnifier-stick' class='stick-appears'></div> </div>");

// When clicking on the icon appears the input form
if($("#magnifier")) {
$("#search").on("click", function() {
    if(clicked){ //Allow function to run only first time.
        return 0;
    }else{
        clicked = true;
    }
        $("#magnifier-stick").addClass("animated fadeOut stick-disappears").removeClass("stick-appears");
        $(".search-init").addClass("search-input").removeClass("search-init");
        setTimeout(function() {     //waits for 1s
            $("#search").html("<div class='search-input'><form><input id='input-form' class='animated fadeIn' type='text' name='searchContent' placeholder='Type Your Search Here...'></form></div>");
            $("#input-form").focus();
        }, 1000);
});
}
 //After pressing Enter, 
 $("#search").on("submit", function(e) {
      var searchText = $("#input-form").val(); //<---JQuery  var searchText = document.getElementById("input-form").value; <---In javascript
      moveSearchUp(searchText);
     return false;
 });

 //send request to API


 //search-input moves up 
 function moveSearchUp(searchText) {
$(".search-input").addClass("search-top").removeClass("search-input");

setTimeout(function() {     //waits for 1s

            //$("#search").html("<div class='search-top'><form><input id='input-form' class='animated fadeIn' type='text' name='searchContent' value='" + searchText + "'></form></div>");
            $("#input-form").css({'width': searchText.length * 7 + 'px'});
        }, 500);
//$("#input-form").attr("disabled", "disabled"); //Disable textbox to prevent
$("#input-form").prop('disabled', true);
$("#input-form").attr("disabled", "disabled"); //Disable textbox to prevent multiple submit
$("#input-form").on("click", function(e) {
    return false;
});

   //   return false;
  } // end function moveSearchUp


 }); // $(document).ready
```

Comment: Thanks for your help vishal patel :) you have a vote

Comment: @Rafa Happy to help